# Either $\alpha = (12345)^{-1}(345)^{-1}(12345)(345)$ or $\beta = (12)(34)(345)^{-1}(12)(34)(345)$ or $(123)$ must lie in a normal subgroup of $A_5$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to prove the title.

My attempt: both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are commutators and because every 3-cycle $(abc) = (ab)(ac)(ab)(ac)$ is a commutator and even, every three cycle or product thereof is a commutator. Because the three cycles generate $A_5$, every element of a $N \triangleleft A_5$ must be generated by commutators. Suppose $N$ does not contain either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, then $N$ cannot contain both $(12345)$ and $(345)$ or both $(345)$ and $(12)(34)$ and it also contains a commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ or composition of commutators. I'm trying to get to a contradiction, but I'm not seeing what property of $N$ I should use, I know that $xN = Nx$ for all $x$, but that is pretty much it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to prove that any non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $A_5$ must contain at least one element among $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Also, I guess the ultimate goal is to show that $A_5$ is simple, and that we should not use that...

Comment: @ArnaudD. yes, you understand it perfectly

Comment: @ArnaudD. I think I get it, can you check if this is correct? We will only write the indices, so an arbritary 3 cycle will be (123). Any element in $N$ is even, so it is either equal to $(123)$ or $(12345)$, or $(12)(34)$ must be in $N$. If $(123) \in N$ we are done (ultimate goal is to show at least one 3 cycle is in $N$). If $(12345) \in N$, then $(543)(12345)(345)$ as well (N is normal), so $\alpha$ as well. If $(12)(34) \in N$ we can show the same way $\beta \in N$. If this is correct the question was wrong, apologies for confusing you.